# Issue on emulating external storage in am335xevm

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-4.2-jelly-bean, mount

I want to bring up JellyBean sources into **am335xevm** board. The board was booted with JellyBean.

I also want to mount */data/media/* as **external storage** on my board. I have refered this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/config-example.html) to achieve that.

I have used following codes in my **init.vendor.rc** file

```
on init
    # for backwards compatibility
    mkdir /mnt/shell/emulated 0700 shell shell
    mkdir /storage/emulated 0555 root root

    export EXTERNAL_STORAGE /storage/emulated/legacy
    export EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE /mnt/shell/emulated
    export EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET /storage/emulated

    symlink /storage/emulated/legacy /sdcard
    symlink /storage/emulated/legacy /mnt/sdcard
    symlink /storage/emulated/legacy /storage/sdcard0
    symlink /mnt/shell/emulated/0 /storage/emulated/legacy

on post-fs-data
    mkdir /data/media 0770 media_rw media_rw
    chown media_rw media_rw /data/media

on fs
    setprop ro.crypto.fuse_sdcard true

service sdcard /system/bin/sdcard /data/media /mnt/shell/emulated 1023 1023
    class main
```

and storage_list.xml file

```
<storage android:mountPoint="/storage/sdcard0"
             android:storageDescription="@string/storage_internal"
             android:primary="true"
             android:emulated="true"
             android:mtpReserve="100" />
```

I'm putting prints on /system/core/sdcard/sdcard.c also.

When I see logs for this, it was getting crashed frequently. I've attached the logcat also here.

```
I/installd(  265): installd firing up
E/cutils  (  265): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
D/installd(  265): Upgrading /data/media for multi-user
D/installd(  265): Upgrading to shared /data/media/obb
F/libc    (  267): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000002 (code=1), thread 267 (sdcard)
F/libc    (  267): Unable to open connection to debuggerd: Connection refused
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
D/Sdcard  (  267): Entered into main argc are: 5
D/Sdcard  (  267): Inside for loop i = 1 argv is /data/media
D/Sdcard  (  267): Source path is set
D/Sdcard  (  267): Loop 1 is finished
D/Sdcard  (  267): Inside for loop i = 2 argv is /mnt/shell/emulated
D/Sdcard  (  267): Dest path is set
D/Sdcard  (  267): Loop 2 is finished
D/Sdcard  (  267): Inside for loop i = 3 argv is 1023
D/Sdcard  (  267): Uid is set
D/Sdcard  (  267): Loop 3 is finished
D/Sdcard  (  267): Inside for loop i = 4 argv is 1023
D/Sdcard  (  267): Gid is set
D/Sdcard  (  267): Loop 4 is finished
I/DEBUG   (  260): debuggerd: Apr 30 2014 15:34:12
I/Vold    (  258): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
D/Vold    (  258): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (  258): Volume media state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (  258): Volume usb state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
I/Netd    (  259): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController(  259): Warning (Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net intery
D/Vold    (  258): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 2 (Pending)
D/Vold    (  258): Volume sdcard state changing 2 (Pending) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
E/DirectVolume(  258): Partition '/devices/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:0001/block/mmcblk1/mmcblk1p3' has a different major than its disk!
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
D/libEGL  (  261): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/gralloc (  261): using (fd=12)
I/gralloc (  261): id           = DA8xx FB Drv
I/gralloc (  261): xres         = 320 px
I/gralloc (  261): yres         = 240 px
I/gralloc (  261): xres_virtual = 320 px
I/gralloc (  261): yres_virtual = 480 px
I/gralloc (  261): bpp          = 16
I/gralloc (  261): r            = 11:5
I/gralloc (  261): g            =  5:6
I/gralloc (  261): b            =  0:5
I/gralloc (  261): width        = 51 mm (159.372543 dpi)
I/gralloc (  261): height       = 38 mm (160.421051 dpi)
I/gralloc (  261): refresh rate = 61.01 Hz
E/SurfaceFlinger(  261): hwcomposer module not found
W/SurfaceFlinger(  261): getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 16390756
W/SurfaceFlinger(  261): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying without EGL_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET_ANDROID
W/SurfaceFlinger(  261): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying without EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID
W/SurfaceFlinger(  261): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying with 16-bit color allowed
W/SurfaceFlinger(  261): EGL_SLOW_CONFIG selected!
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): EGL informations:
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): vendor    : Android
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): extensions: EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer 
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): Client API: OpenGL_ES
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x0
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): OpenGL ES informations:
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): vendor    : Android
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.4
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_palette 
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
I/SurfaceFlinger(  261): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096 x 4096
D/SurfaceFlinger(  261): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0x40c8e318
D/libEGL  (  296): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/ARMAssembler(  296): generated scanline__00000077:03010102_00008A01_00000000 [  9 ipp] (30 ins) at [0x409921f0:0x40992268] in 274659 ns
D/AndroidRuntime(  262): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  262): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  262): CheckJNI is ON
I/mediaserver(  264): ServiceManager: 0x40cadee8
I/AudioFlinger(  264): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService(  264): CameraService started (pid=264)
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase(  264): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
E/audio_hw_primary(  264): Duplicate path setting '(null)'
E/audio_hw_primary(  264): Duplicate path setting '(null)'
E/audio_hw_primary(  264): Duplicate path setting '(null)'
I/AudioFlinger(  264): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Rowboat audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
I/AudioFlinger(  264): HAL output buffer size 880 frames, normal mix buffer size 1056 frames
I/AudioMixer(  264): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
E/MonoPipe(  264): Failed to fetch local time frequency when constructing a MonoPipe (res = -32).  getNextWriteTimestamp calls will be non-functional
D/dalvikvm(  262): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'core.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---
D/dalvikvm(  373): Ignoring duplicate verify attempt on Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm(  373): Ignoring duplicate verify attempt on Ljava/lang/Class;
D/dalvikvm(  373): Ignoring duplicate verify attempt on Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;
D/dalvikvm(  373): Ignoring duplicate verify attempt on Ljava/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue;
D/MDnsDS  (  259): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  (  259): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  (  259): Going to poll with pollCount 1
D/dalvikvm(  373): Ignoring duplicate verify attempt on Ljava/lang/ref/FinalizerReference;
F/libc    (  494): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000002 (code=1), thread 494 (sdcard)
D/Sdcard  (  494): Entered into main argc are: 5
D/Sdcard  (  494): Inside for loop i = 1 argv is /data/media
D/Sdcard  (  494): Source path is set
D/Sdcard  (  494): Loop 1 is finished
D/Sdcard  (  494): Inside for loop i = 2 argv is /mnt/shell/emulated
D/Sdcard  (  494): Dest path is set
D/Sdcard  (  494): Loop 2 is finished
D/Sdcard  (  494): Inside for loop i = 3 argv is 1023
D/Sdcard  (  494): Uid is set
D/Sdcard  (  494): Loop 3 is finished
D/Sdcard  (  494): Inside for loop i = 4 argv is 1023
D/Sdcard  (  494): Gid is set
D/Sdcard  (  494): Loop 4 is finished
I/DEBUG   (  260): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  260): Build fingerprint: 'Android/twizzler/twizzler:4.2.2/JDQ39/eng.root.20140429.171356:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  260): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  260): pid: 494, tid: 494, name: sdcard  >>> /system/bin/sdcard <<<
I/DEBUG   (  260): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000002
I/DEBUG   (  260):     r0 00000002  r1 0000003b  r2 00000002  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     r4 bed6eb28  r5 00000004  r6 00000000  r7 00000002
I/DEBUG   (  260):     r8 bed6e06c  r9 bed6e6a4  sl bed6e6a4  fp bed6eb2c
I/DEBUG   (  260):     ip 00000073  sp bed6dfb0  lr 40169e71  pc 40163540  cpsr 20000010
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d0  652f6c6c6568736d  d1  203a657261206375
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d2  000000000000006c  d3  0000000000000061
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  0085219f00000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d16 4160a433f2e978d5  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d18 41c59a83b3800000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  260):     scr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #00  pc 00019540  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+16)
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #01  pc 0001fe6d  /system/lib/libc.so (__vfprintf+2124)
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #02  pc 000212b3  /system/lib/libc.so (vsnprintf+70)
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #03  pc 0000139d  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_buf_print+44)
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #04  pc 00002335  /system/bin/sdcard
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #05  pc 000126f7  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #06  pc 00000e70  /system/bin/sdcard
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df70  bed6e72c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df74  40167f23  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df78  bed6e6a4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df7c  bed6e028  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df80  00000013  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df84  bed6e028  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df88  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df8c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df90  bed6eccd  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df94  bed6e074  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df98  bed6e6a4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6df9c  00000013  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfa0  ffffffed  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfa4  40169617  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfa8  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #00  bed6dfb0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #01  bed6dfb0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfb4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfb8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfbc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfc0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfc4  00000073  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfc8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfcc  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfd0  bed6e06c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfd4  400fe947  /system/bin/sdcard
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfd8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfdc  0000004b  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfe0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfe4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfe8  400fe914  /system/bin/sdcard
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6dfec  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  260):     #02  bed6e690  400fc7aa  /system/bin/sdcard
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e694  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e698  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e69c  00000009  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6a0  00004000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6a4  bed6e73f  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6a8  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6ac  000003c4  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6b0  ffff0208  [vectors]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6b4  bed6e704  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6b8  000003ff  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6bc  400fe84f  /system/bin/sdcard
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6c0  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6c4  bed6e704  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6c8  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  260):          bed6e6cc  400992a3  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_buf_write+186)
I/DEBUG   (  260):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb08 400fff14 000003ff 400fe84f 400fe914  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb18 400fe339 400fe914 bed6ecc1 bed6eccd  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb28 00000002 00000022 00001000 bed6eb54  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb38 00000002 bed6ebc4 400fe897 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb48 00000667 000005f9 ffffffff bed6ecea  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb58 00000000 400fe1b5 bed6ebb4 00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb68 bed6ebcc 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb78 bed6ebac 4015c6f9 bed6eb98 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb88 00000000 00000000 00000000 400fce74  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb98 400ffddc 400ffde4 400ffdec bed6ebb0  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eba8 00000000 40133bbb 00000005 bed6ecae  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6ebb8 bed6ecc1 bed6eccd bed6ece1 bed6ece6  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6ebc8 00000000 bed6eceb bed6ed28 bed6ed50  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6ebd8 bed6ed63 bed6ed78 bed6ed93 bed6eda6  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6ebe8 bed6edbf bed6edd9 bed6edf2 bed6ef46  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6ebf8 bed6ef70 bed6ef9c bed6efc6 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e04c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e05c 00000000 00000000 400fe935 00000010  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e06c bed6eccd 00000013 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e07c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e08c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e09c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e0ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e0bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e0cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e0dc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e0ec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e0fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e10c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e11c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e12c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e13c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e684 000003ff 400fff14 4016b2b7 400fc7aa  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e694 00000000 00000000 00000009 00004000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6a4 bed6e73f 00000003 000003c4 ffff0208  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6b4 bed6e704 000003ff 400fe84f 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6c4 bed6e704 00000003 400992a3 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6d4 bed6e694 bed6e6d4 00000001 400fe84f  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6e4 00000007 bed6e704 00000013 40195228  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6f4 400fe84f 40195228 400993a1 bed6eb20  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e704 72756f73 705f6563 20687461 2f207369  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e714 61746164 64656d2f 64206169 5f747365  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e724 68746170 20736920 746e6d2f 6568732f  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e734 652f6c6c 616c756d 6f646574 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e744 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e754 00000000 00000000 40047d74 4014aed4  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e764 000000a0 00000004 40047d5c 4013f88c  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e774 40046114 40046f54 00000004 bed6e7c8  
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e684 000003ff 400fff14 4016b2b7 400fc7aa  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e694 00000000 00000000 00000009 00004000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6a4 bed6e73f 00000003 000003c4 ffff0208  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6b4 bed6e704 000003ff 400fe84f 00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6c4 bed6e704 00000003 400992a3 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6d4 bed6e694 bed6e6d4 00000001 400fe84f  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6e4 00000007 bed6e704 00000013 40195228  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e6f4 400fe84f 40195228 400993a1 bed6eb20  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e704 72756f73 705f6563 20687461 2f207369  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e714 61746164 64656d2f 64206169 5f747365  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e724 68746170 20736920 746e6d2f 6568732f  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e734 652f6c6c 616c756d 6f646574 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e744 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e754 00000000 00000000 40047d74 4014aed4  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e764 000000a0 00000004 40047d5c 4013f88c  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6e774 40046114 40046f54 00000004 bed6e7c8  
I/DEBUG   (  260): 
I/DEBUG   (  260): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb0c 000003ff 400fe84f 400fe914 400fe339  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb1c 400fe914 bed6ecc1 bed6eccd 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  260):     bed6eb2c 0^Z[1] + Stopped              logcat 
root@android:/ # [   51.934753] warning: `zygote' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
[   68.456970] request_suspend_state: wakeup (3->0) at 68414745129 (2000-01-01 00:01:07.347010007 UTC)
[   69.688903] acc_open
[   69.691253] acc_release
[  111.173339] init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003  name:service.bootanim.exit
```

What might be the problem for crash? I have searched lot. But, I didn't get any solution. Whether I'm doing is correct or not?

Please anyone share your view?